# why is datetime not recording time when stored?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

When recording a TimeStamp into the the table in the DB why does...

```
DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Today;

BookingRecord newBooking = new BookingRecord();
//other code for adding record to db
newBooking.TimeStamp = todaysDate;
```

why does the record in timeStamp record as : 2013-09-04 00:00:00.000
I want the correct time to display as well?

thanks for reply

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because DateTime.Today is actually supposed to do that. Use DateTime.Now if you want the time information as well.

Edit: of course, it's recommended to use UTC DateTimes for storage in the database anyway, so it's probably best to use DateTime.UtcNow!

Comment: ok great thanks for the help. What about if i wanted to store the 2013-09-04 01:03:00.100 in UK format dd/mm/yyyy 01:03:00.100 how would I do that?

Comment: Assuming the database column is datetime or datetime2, there's no formatting info stored there, just the value; the formatting is decided by whoever outputs the data. The value itself is just the number of ticks (or seconds, depending on database and/or type of field) from a fixed point in the past. It's up to whoever's looking at it to decide how it should be presented.

Comment: o right ok what about if I had the dd/mm/yyyy stored as 3 parameters int day;month;year, how could I use this to add to a record newBooking.Date = (year/month/day)?? I need to convert them to system.datetime?

Comment: You could do that but it would be a bad idea in my opinion. There's a lot of stuff that you get for free (most importantly *correctness*) when using datetimes. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime.Today` will actually be today's date with the time portion set to `00:00:00`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx

> An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to
>   00:00:00.

Comment: ok great thanks for the help. What about if i wanted to store the 2013-09-04 01:03:00.100 in UK format dd/mm/yyyy 01:03:00.100 how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Today;
```

change to

```
DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Now;
```